# Apache Rewrite Rule www to non-www + http to https + add trailing slash

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, codeigniter

I really need the following 3 features of my website:

- www to non-www
- HTTP to HTTPS
- force trailing slash at the end of the URLs

I have a current implementation but I **face a very bad bug**.

When I manually enter the URL `example.com/page` in the browser the browser redirects to `example.com/?page/`. This, of course, opens my homepage and not the required `/page/`.

I've tried many examples and read a lot of similar questions for the last few weeks. No success.

Here is my full `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


# Redirects www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# Force ending url traling slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]



# Prevent CI index.php

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$0 [L]

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Redirects http to https protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


# Redirect index.php to the root /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# One month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>

RedirectPermanent /free-project-management-certification/ https://example.com/projectmanagement/
RedirectPermanent /free-scrum-master-certification/ https://example.com/scrummaster/
RedirectPermanent /product-owner-certification/ https://example.com/productowner/
RedirectPermanent /human-resources-management-certification/ https://example.com/humanresources/
RedirectPermanent /product-management-certification/ https://example.com/productmanagement/
RedirectPermanent /project-management-certification/ https://example.com/projectmanagement/

RedirectPermanent /index.php/ https://example.com/


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I changed the positions of all redirects, tried different combinations, changed characters, a lot of things. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> # Redirects http to https protocol
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place. It needs to be at the top of your `.htaccess` file, immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive and before the www to non-www redirect. (You are also missing `R` and `L` flags to trigger a *permanent* redirect and prevent further processing.)

It is currently being called after the URL has been rewritten to `index.php?page/` (which is after the first redirect to append the slash). So, the HTTP to HTTPS redirect ends up redirecting to `https://example.com/index.php?page/` and another redirect then removes the `index.php` to finally end up at `/?page/` - 3 redirects in all!

In other words:

- Request `http://example.com/page` (HTTP)
- 301 redirect to `http://example.com/page/` (append trailing slash)
- Internal rewrite to `http://example.com/index.php?page/`
- 302 redirect to `http://example.com/index.php?page/` (since missing `R=301` flag on directive)
- 301 redirect to `http://example.com/?page/` (removal of `index.php`).

As mentioned, you need to move your HTTP to HTTPS redirect to the start of the file (this is the correct order if you intend to implement HSTS in the future):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirects http to https protocol
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirects www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You could reverse these two rules to prevent a potential double redirect when requesting `http://www.example.com/` (ie. HTTP + www), however, this won't be HSTS compliant (which states that you must redirect to HTTPS on the same host).

However, you still have further conflicts between your mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond`) rewrites and mod_alias (`RedirectPermanent`) redirects. You should avoid mixing redirects from both modules.

> ```
> RedirectPermanent /index.php/ https://example.com/
> ```

This `RedirectPermanent` directive is not required. You are already performing the necessary redirect (to remove `index.php` from the visible URL) with mod_rewrite earlier in the code. Although the corresponding mod_rewrite directive would not catch a URL that contained trailing path-info:

> ```
> # Redirect index.php to the root /
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Omit the trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to allow for optional trailing slashes (ie. path-info) to also be caught. ie. `RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php /$1 [R=301,L]`.

> ```
> RedirectPermanent /free-project-management-certification/ https://example.com/projectmanagement/
> RedirectPermanent /free-scrum-master-certification/ https://example.com/scrummaster/
> RedirectPermanent /product-owner-certification/ https://example.com/productowner/
> RedirectPermanent /human-resources-management-certification/ https://example.com/humanresources/
> RedirectPermanent /product-management-certification/ https://example.com/productmanagement/
> RedirectPermanent /project-management-certification/ https://example.com/projectmanagement/
> ```

You should also convert the remaining mod_alias `RedirectPermanent` directives to corresponding mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` redirects and place them *near the start of your file* (either at the very top, immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive or after the canonical www to non-www / HTTP to HTTPS redirects) in order to avoid further conflicts.

Currently, with using mod_alias `RedirectPermanent`, requesting any one of these "redirected" URLs will also exhibit similar behaviour. eg. Request `/free-project-management-certification/` and you will be externally redirected to `/projectmanagement/?free-project-management-certification/` due to earlier rewrites (regardless of whether you request HTTP or HTTPS initially).

I assume these are intended to be 1 to 1 redirects. (Although the `RedirectPermanent` directive is strictly a many to many redirect due to its prefix-matching nature.)

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^free-project-management-certification/$ /projectmanagement/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^free-scrum-master-certification/$ /scrummaster/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product-owner-certification/$ /productowner/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^human-resources-management-certification/$ /humanresources/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product-management-certification/$ /productmanagement/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^project-management-certification/$ /projectmanagement/ [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** If you include these redirects at the very top of the file then you could include a full absolute URL (as you did initially) for the target URL, to avoid multiple redirects when requesting the non-canonical HTTP or www subdomain. eg. `https://example.com/projectmanagement/`.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and/or with browser caching disabled to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working!
Just these RewriteRule ^free-project-management-certification/$ /projectmanagement/ [R=301,L] redirect to the index page but they are not that important.

Comment: Have you moved those specific redirects for old pages to the start of the file? (Actually, it would perhaps be preferable to include an absolute URL in those redirects - to avoid multiple redirects when requesting non-canonical HTTP and/or www. eg. `RewriteRule ^free-project-management-certification/$ https://example.com/projectmanagement/ [R=301,L]`